Ошибка копирования изображения с помощью Gulp
Есть простая задача копирования изображения из папки в другую папку.
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('./img/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./image'));
});

Раньше у меня все нормально работало, но с недавнего времени мои изображения копируются в итоговую папку поврежденными. При попытке их открытия появляется ошибка о повреждении файла и невозможности его чтения.
Версии gulp:
CLI version: 3.0.0
Local version: 5.0.0
Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема и как его исправить, и даже объяснить проблему было затруднительно. Может это проблема моего ПК, системы или версии Gulp и т. д., не понятно. Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой пожалуйста поделитесь решением.
Заранее спасибо!

Короче. Оказалось всё это из-за версии локального gulp. Я установил версию 4.0.2 которая работала на моем последнем проекте и установил его вместо 5.0.0.
